# How to Disable Silverstripe Elemental Blocks on Separate Blog/s?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We are working on a Silverstripe project that uses the [Elemental Module](https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental) to layout content.

The project also uses the Blog Module with the blog being used for two sections of the website - the work portfolio & a standard blog.

The challenge is: we want different content behaviour for each blog/section:

1. Portfolio - Element Blocks
2. Blog - standard blog/page behaviour

What is the best way to achieve this?

Should we extend `Blog` & `BlogPost` to new objects `Portfolio` & `PortfolioItem` to separate out the two different behaviours?

Or can we just add the following to the Blog Object/Controller:

```
if ($this->BlogType == 'portfolio'){
  // enable Elemental
} else {
  // disable Elemental
}
```

And finally, how do we disable Elemental on specific Pages? It isn't obvious in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This was our solution - using the `includeElemental` method to disable/ enable Elemental on a case by case basis.

```
class BlogPostExtension extends DataExtension
{
  public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields){
    $fields->insertBefore(new 
       DropdownField("LayoutIndex", "Layout", ["Portfolio", "Blog"]), "Title");
  }

  public function includeElemental(){
    if ($this->owner->LayoutIndex == 0) {
      return true;
    } else if ($this->owner->LayoutIndex == 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }   
}
```